# Pasar un programa de ejecutarse en comandos a tener un mejor aspecto visual

Tags: c++

Explico:

Pase un algoritmo que tenía en pseint a c++ y el programa cumple con su funcion(Da los resultados bien).

Lo que quiero ahora es hacerle un entorno grafico(que se vea como los programas ya terminados).

Es decir que se deje de ver como un programa que solo se ven las lineas de entrada y salida En una pantalla negra con letras blancas(como cuando usamos la consola cmd en window) a un programa con diferentes colores y demas aspecros visuales.

Ej: si hice un programita que halla el area de una circunferencia.

Quisiera que esté una imagen de una circunferncia. Y debajo pida en un recuadro el radio y debajo de este un boton para calcular el area.

Creo que fui lo mas claro posible.

Gracias por sus respuestas de antemano

Comment: posible duplicado http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4824/c%C3%B3mo-pasar-el-programa-en-c-que-est%C3%A1-como-cmd-a-estar-como-los-programas-norm

Comment: creo que el link de arriba puede ayudar en lo que busca, usted lo que busca es una "libreria/biblioteca" para mostrar graficos y/o manejar ventanas ect. Por otro lado igual le ayuda estos video -> https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7416233364DDD353 y -> https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLkMd51xTELZLS4NQl71uOPvMPRveD9C1o Saludos

Comment: simple sample https://youtu.be/ScZn-cQiVFs?t=222 Saludos

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Como se llama esa parte de la creacion de un software. Ej: compilar, depurar. Esa parte como se llama. Asi quizas se me pude facilitar la busqueda en internet

Comment: igual esto te ayuda un poco no es para c++ pero igual con ello entiendes mejor http://www.fdi.ucm.es/profesor/jpavon/poo/tema6resumido.pdf o este que si es basado en c++ https://books.google.es/books?id=KUl9OqsCYOQC&pg=PA370&lpg=PA370&dq=implementar+interfaz+usuario+c%2B%2B&source=bl&ots=D9eFdpeBlM&sig=RK4ryALoAH1ndyZ9EgQUYccTRSI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTp6eNgZjLAhVDxRQKHQczAG4Q6AEIXjAI#v=onepage&q=implementar%20interfaz%20usuario%20c%2B%2B&f=false Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel gracias

Answer (score 4):

Lo que quieres es transformar una aplicación de consola de tipo línea de comandos  ([CLI=command line interface](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interfaz_de_l%C3%ADnea_de_comandos)) a una aplicación con interfaz gráfica [GUI= Graphical User Interface](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interfaz_de_texto). No hay recetas generales; eso es muy dependiente del lenguaje, del tipo de aplicación y (salvo con Java) del sistema operativo (Windows o Linux) .

Un primera decisión a tomar es si quieres hacer una aplicación realmente gráfica, o te conformas con pasar a una [interfaz de texto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interfaz_de_texto) - en este caso, 
hay distintas librerías, en Linux y C el estandar es [ncurses](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Si quieres una interfaz propiamente gráfica, tienes que elegir una librería, para lo cual lo primero que tienes que definir varias cosas:

- ¿Cuál es mi sistema operativo y lenguage de programación?
- ¿Qué tipo de interactividad necesita mi aplicación? ¿Es solo una interfaz para recibir parámetros y mostrar resultados? (en el otro extremos estaría un juego, por ejemplo)
- ¿Quiero hacer una GUI que llame a mi programa de consola, o quiero hacer un nuevo programa?

Desde ya, te advierto que hacerlo en C puede ser bastante trabajo. En todo caso, no es para nada recomandable intentarlo si estás comenzando a programar. Un ejemplo de librería es portable (Windows-Unix) es [wxwidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/). Es un poco más fácil (sólo un poco) en otros lenguajes. Si nos das más detalles de tu contexto, quizás podamos ayudarte mejor.